# disable/enable text-box depending on check-boxes

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using cakePHP framework to work on my project.

How do I enable a textbox when a the checkbox is check, and disable it when it's unchecked? I tried javascript but it isn't working and I think it is because of my 'id'. How should I declare my 'id'?

Here is my code. It is in a forLoop.

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('menu_item_id',
                            array(
                                    'value' => $items[$i]['MenuItem']['menu_item_id'],
                                    'hiddenField' => false,
                                    'name' => 'data[OrderItem][menu_item_id][]',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'div' => false,
                                    )
                                ); 

echo $this->Form->input('quantity', 
                        array(
                            'style'=>'width:65px; height:25px;',
                            'name' => 'data[OrderItem][quantity][]',
                            'div' => false,
                            'label' => false
                            )
                        );

echo $this->Form->input('notes', 
                        array(
                            'style'=>'width:65px; height:25px;',
                            'name' => 'data[OrderItem][notes][]',
                            'div' => false,
                            'label' => false
                            )
                        );
```

By the way, I am a beginner both in cakePHP and Javascript. Thanks.

I made some changes. In my script, I added this

```
 

    
        function changeStatus(){
            if(document.getElementById("my_checkbox").checked == true){
                document.getElementById("input_field").disabled= false;
                alert('a');
            } else {
                document.getElementById("input_field").disabled= true;
                alert("B");
            }
        }
```

*alerts are for testing. it goes to the proper block, but it does not enabled/disabled the textfield. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please post the markup generated instead of the PHP source code

Comment: so your real question is, In CakePHP - how to assign value to id attribute of Text Input.am i right?

Comment: @gnanz, yes. sort of. and also on how to add javascript on it.

Comment: alerts are just for testing. :)

Comment: there is no such property as `enabled` for any element. You should use `disabled=true` and `disabled=false`. Or you could use `element.setAttribute("disabled", true);` and `element.removeAttribute("disabled");`

Comment: @Preetam yes, just changed it. it is now sort of working, but there's something wrong. whatever checkbox i checked, it only enables the first textbox. like if i checked the second checkbox, it should enabled the second textbox, but it enables the first.

Comment: that is because you have given a single id only..`document.getElementById("THIS SHOULD BE DIFFERENT")`
one way is to make two functions for both the checkboxes where id should be different as according. or you could make a single function using jquery but that would be a little complicated as you don't know much about jquery and javascript. Even though if you want I can post an answer with it.

Comment: @Preetam i would be very much willing to explore jquery if it could solve my problem. thanks.

Comment: Hi guys. This problem is solved. :) Thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **checkbox** array => add

```
"onclick'=>'changeStatus(this);"
```

if **this** keyword not works for you then replace that with checkbox id 'menu_item_id'

then write normail javascript function to disable inputbox

```
function changeStatus(obj){
if(obj.checked){
document.getElementById("quantity").disabled =true;
}
```

Single line JS is to use below line, it will toggle between two states

```
document.getElementById("quantity").disabled =obj.checked;
```

**Update** : Check whether the below code working for you

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('menu_item_id_'.$i,
                            array(
                                    'value' => $items[$i]['MenuItem']['menu_item_id'],
                                    'hiddenField' => false,
                                    'name' => 'data[OrderItem][menu_item_id][]',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'div' => false,
                                     "onclick'=>'changeStatus(this,$i);"
                                    )
                                ); 

echo $this->Form->input('quantity_'.$i, 
                        array(
                            'style'=>'width:65px; height:25px;',
                            'name' => 'data[OrderItem][quantity][]',
                            'div' => false,
                            'label' => false
                            )
                        );


 function changeStatus(obj,index){
     document.getElementById("quantity_"+index).disabled = ! obj.checked;
    }
```

Comment: do i have to add 'id' in my checkbox array? i am not sure though if i am doin the right thing, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Updated my answer, check now

Comment: i tried passing the index, but it turns out that it $i was not passed in the function changeStatus().

Comment: can u check the html source generated using 'View Source' option in browsers for how the code is generated

Answer (score 1):

By dfault cakephp assigns id to any element with normal convention which is `UsersMenuItemId` (I am assuming users is your model here). But you can assign id with other htmlOptions like

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('menu_item_id',
                        array(
                                'id' => 'my_checkbox',
                                'value' => $items[$i]['MenuItem']['menu_item_id'],
                                'hiddenField' => false,
                                'name' => 'data[OrderItem][menu_item_id][]',
                                'label' => false,
                                'div' => false,
                                )
                            );
```

Now write a basic script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#my_checkbox').event('click', function(){
          if($('#my_checkbox').is(':checked')){
             $('#input_field').removeAttr('disabled');                 
          } else {
             $('#input_field').attr('disabled','disabled');
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('menu_item_id',
                            array(
                                    'value' => $items[$i]['MenuItem']['menu_item_id'],
                                    'hiddenField' => false,
                                    'name' => 'data[OrderItem][menu_item_id][]',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'div' => false,
                                    )
                                );
```

here first field you declared 'menu_item_id' is for table name or we can say model name.

there is different option for assigning id to input like:

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('modelname',
                                array(
                                        'value' => $items[$i]['MenuItem']['menu_item_id'],
                                        'hiddenField' => false,
                                        'name' => 'data[OrderItem][menu_item_id][]',
                                        'label' => false,
                                        'div' => false,
                                        'id'=>'your-id'
                                        )
                                    );
```

but keep in mind that id must be unique on the page.

Comment: I get your point. Given that these check-boxes are generated by the for-loop, what should be the correct way of naming my id?

Comment: to use jquery you can use class instead of id,because classes are not unique or other way to use id is you can append any loop variable with id like : i+"your_id" , where i is loop variable which will increment on every loop(i++).